# Просмотр наличия ошибок при использовании log4j.appender

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Задача: запись логов в бд.

Проблема: как можно словить ошибки, которые я получаю при запись в бд моих логов? т.е. смогу ли я получить ошибку если нет коннекта или неверный логин/пасс?

Настройки `appender`'a:

```
log4j.appender.db = org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.db.URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/log_db
log4j.appender.db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
log4j.appender.db.user=root
log4j.appender.db.password=1234
log4j.appender.db.sql = INSERT INTO s_logs(container, date, level, package_class, id_name_ver_bundle, message) VALUES ('${karaf.name}','%d{ISO8601}','%p','%c','%X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version}','%m')
log4j.appender.db.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.db.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Версия логера:

```
 <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
```

Comment: вы хотите получить ошибки от самого `appender`? т.е. `appender` не может записать что-то в БД.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, всё верно, возможно ли их получить и попробовать записать в консоль/файл/другую бд